# Powershell - Test-Path - If and return don't work

Tags: powershell

i am new to Powershell, the following if statement is executed even when the return of Test-Path is true.

```
$CheckFile = Test-Path $output_folder\$item

if ($CheckFile = "False"){
     Does something
}
```

Honestly i don't know why.

For further Information, just ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$CheckFile = "False"` -> `$CheckFile -eq $False`

Comment: You're assigning with `=`, not comparing. And you're checking against a string with `"False"`, not a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a string value of `"False"` which, when interpreted as a boolean will always be `true`, because it's a string that has a value. Beyond the string being empty or not, the value is not used in that conversion.

You're also using the assignment operator `=` not the equality operator `-eq`. Use `$False`:

```
$CheckFile = Test-Path $output_folder\$item

if ($CheckFile -eq $False){
     Does something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a mistake due to my inexperience with Powershell